# Internal server error on admin/modules/list/confirm

Tags: 7

I have recently decided to move one of the sites to another hosting provider, and now started to receive this 500 error when submitting changes to admin/modules. The new hosting has different environment where all sites might have their core and contributed modules connected to the central repository; now, in admin/modules all 850 local repository modules can be seen as they were in sites/all/modules. In server logs this error reflect as:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87437 bytes) in /opt/drupal7/includes/cache.inc on line 463, referer: admin/modules
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /opt/drupal7/includes/form.inc on line 1820
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8208 bytes) in /opt/drupal7/modules/field/field.crud.inc on line 711, referer: admin/modules?render=overlay
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /opt/drupal7/includes/file.inc on line 200, referer: admin/modules

The site has a 128 MB memory limit; it is more than on previous hosting, but now some of the enabled modules (like OpenLayers) sometime also issue memory errors (like those above, but on site they work without any 500 errors).

What can be the reason of this errors? Is there any additional information that can help find what to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [White screen of death](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your PHP memory limit on php.ini.
If you use Linux, go to /etc/php.ini to find it out.

Comment: I'v already tried it before posting the question, the memory limit is set to 128 mb

Comment: 850modules,maybe you need more memory

Comment: Yes, it was indeed an account quota issue, the upgrade solved it

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the PHP memory in `settings.php` file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Comment: I'v already tried it before posting the question, the memory limit is set to 128 mb