# How do I delete all terms in a vocabulary?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, drush

As reported [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54680/taxonomy-too-many-tags) I have big problems with huge vocabularies in Drupal 7. Now I want to empty the big vocabularies, but I can't do that via the admin interface, because its running out of memory, so it can't be loaded any more.

How can I delete all terms of a vocabulary form the command line using `drush` and MySQL?

I know, I could do something like that:

```
DELETE FROM `database`.`taxonomy_term_data` WHERE  `taxonomy_term_data`.`vid` = 17
```

But what else would I have to delete?