# Render custom block by block name

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have created a custom block in the Drupal CMS. Say it is called "test_block". Is there a way to render this block in a template file using the name of the block?

Thanks,

Comment: Here [Follow this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58987/printing-a-block-in-node-tpl-php)

Comment: I have post my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**D7:**

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  print $block['content'];
?>
```

**'module_name'** = The machine name of the module (i.e. the module's folder name). This is true for core modules too, so for instance 'search', 'user' and 'comment' would all work here.

**'block_delta'** = The machine name of the block. You can determine what this is by visiting the block administration page and editing the block. The URL for editing a webform block, for instance, would be something like:

Drupal 7: admin/structure/block/manage/**webform**/**client-block-11**/configure

In this example, **'webform'** is the module's name, **'client-block-11'** is the block's delta.

Custom blocks will have module name of 'block' and a number for a delta, which you can also find by editing the block.

More information: http://drupal.org/node/26502

====== OR =============

```
<?php
//suppose 98 is the id of the block

   $block =block_load('block',98);
   $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));        
   print $output;
?>
```

Comment: The D7 solution won't universally work, because $block['content'] might be a renderable array instead of a string of html. Also, this method will only render the content, without the '#theme' => 'block' wrapper.

Comment: The other D7 solution will cause a notice or sth, because drupal_render() has a by-reference parameter.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/957038#comment-12723048

Comment: Thanks :) This help me lot

Answer (score 4):

### D8:

```
$block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(BLOCK_ID);// BLOCK_ID
$block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'DISPLAY_VIEW_NAME');
$rendered_block = ['#markup' => render($block_view)];
```

[Render a custom block programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195916/render-a-custom-block-programmatically/195917#195917)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'test_block');
print render($block['content']);
```

Comment: This doesnt solves the problem. I tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to use a custom template for this block, then the answer is:

Assuming the machine name of your block is test_block, then create a file called

```
 block--block--test_block.tpl.php
```

In your theme

Answer (score 0):

On your template level you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
  $test_block = "test_block";
  print views_embed_view($test_block);
?>
```

This will display your block in the template.