# Render a custom block programmatically

Tags: 8, blocks

How do I render a custom block type (block_content) programmatically with a specific display view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `hook_preprocess_page()` add the following code.

```
$block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(BLOCK_ID);// BLOCK_ID
$block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'DISPLAY_VIEW_NAME');
if ($block_view) {
    $variables['page']['my_block'] = $block_view;
}
```

In your Twig template, print the block with the following code.

```
{% if page.my_block %}
  {{ page.my_block }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How to know what is block id and DISPLAY_VIEW_NAME in views in drupal 8?

Comment: `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id')` and `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('display_id')`

Answer (score 4):

If your block is custom, this worked for me:

```
$customblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('{id of block here}', []);
```

Then you could print it from your preprocess like so:

```
if(isset($customblock) && !empty($customblock)) {
  $variables['logo'] = $customblock->build();
}
```

When you created your block, you would have set the ID here:

```
/**
  * Provides a 'Logo' Block.
  *
  * @Block(
  *   id = "logo",
  *   admin_label = @Translation("Logo"),
  *   category = @Translation("Header"),
  * )
  */
```

However, this method stops contextual links from displaying. To work around this you can do the following:

```
$Block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($id);
if(isset($Block) && !empty($Block)) {
  $Block =  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($Block);
}
```

Please note: the block needs to be placed in a region in the block layout page (but can be set to Disabled) and the $id is equal to the instance of that block, NOT what you defined in the .php file. This can be found by hovering on any of the block links in block layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the block as a View you can use [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.7.x) in your template_preprocess_page function, something like:

`$variables['my_block'] = views_embed_view('view_machine_name', 'block_machine_name');`

Sub in the View and block machine names. View name visible at admin/structure/views and the block machine name on the specific block's Advanced settings (defaults to 'block_1').