# Show a block on the front page, but only on the first page

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a block that I want to show on the front page, but not on every paged page (i.e., don't show it on /front-page?page=1).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [This module](https://www.drupal.org/project/request_data_conditions) will give you a bunch of extra conditions, one of them being to see if a URL parameter is or isn't set. Might be worth a try. Use at your own risk, it's very much a work in progress

Answer (score 2):

Install and enable [request_data_conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/request_data_conditions) module

Then on the configuration of your block add following settings

- **Pages** as `<front>`
- **URL query parameters** set

  - `page` as `must not be set`
  - `page` as  `must equal`  0
  - uncheck **require all**

[image]

Comment: Or page == 0 (can happen sometimes)

Comment: @clive perhaps this is a better setup than ^

Comment: That's what I always go with, yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the block as shown in screen shot?
[image]

If this block is generated using code, also have a look at code also.

Comment: Yes it is like in screen, but block is showing on <front>/?page.... to, but i want to display block ony on the first page of homepage

Comment: See in this module helps https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups

Comment: i installed that module before asking this question ( module dident solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In hook_preprocess_page() add the following code.

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
$block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(BLOCK_ID);// BLOCK_ID
$block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'DISPLAY_VIEW_NAME');
if ($block_view) {
    $variables['page']['my_block'] = $block_view;
}
}
```

In your Twig template, print the block with the following code.

```
{% if page.my_block %}
  {{ page.my_block }}
{% endif %}
```

Refference: [Render a custom block programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195916/render-a-custom-block-programmatically)