# How to render specific block from template without rendering entire region

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm attempting to render a specific block on a page without rendering the region. I'm assuming the machine name of the block is 23 based on the URL I get when configuring the block.

```
example.org/admin/structure/block/manage/block/23/configure
```

I'm attempting to grab the block using the information I've found here

https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

My attempt at it is

```
$block = module_invoke('block','blockview',23);
print render($block['content']);
```

But I'm not having any luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a block in node.tpl.php](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58987/printing-a-block-in-node-tpl-php)

Comment: -1 from me, because themes should never require certain blocks to be available, or modules enabled. Rendering region is the designed way to do it and shortcuts like this may hurt future developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there it's `block_view` not `blockview`

```
$block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', '2');
print render($block['content']);
```

Comment: oh wow, I was a lot closer than I realized. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, would you make the question as answered.

Comment: Yep sorry, I tried to check it right after you answered but it told me I had to wait a bit.