# MAMP Pro and Drush mem exhaustion

Tags: drush

I have mamp 6.0 installed. When trying to 
drush up
and confirming "yes", I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Users/me/Sites/jla
>   copy/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/includes/stylizer.inc on line
>   911 Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Users/me/Sites/jla
>   copy/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/includes/stylizer.inc, line 911
>   Your memory limit is set to 32M; drush needs as much memory to run
>   as[error] Drupal.  Please check your configuration settings in
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini or in your drush.ini
>   file; see examples/example.drush.ini for details. The external command
>   could not be executed due to an application     [error] error. Illegal
>   string offset 'site' backend.inc:1013                        [warning]
>   The command could not be executed successfully (returned: PHP Fatal 
>   [error] error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Users/me/Sites/jla
>   copy/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/includes/stylizer.inc on line
>   911 , code: 255)

This is the result of my drush status:
 Drupal version                  :  7.10
 Site URI                        :  `http://default`
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database username               :  root
 Database name                   :  jla_d7
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :  Anonymous
 Default theme                   :  jlasitetheme
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP executable                  :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
 PHP configuration               :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini 
 PHP OS                          :  Darwin
 Drush version                   :  6.0
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :
 Drupal root                     :  /Users/me/Sites/jla copy
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Temporary file directory path   :  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php

I know that I have set a 128MB memory_limit in the MAMP php5.4.10 file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White screen of death: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n.b. The error message says that your memory limit is 32MB, not 128MB.  The 128MB setting must be for your web server.  Check the php.ini for PHP CLI; it's quoted in the output of Drush status, above:  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini.  You should find that memory_limit is 32M, or perhaps unset.  Set it to 128M, or perhaps even 256M or more, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I am not familiar with "PHP CLI" but after doing some searches I'm still not sure if it is necessary.  

When I do a "which php", I get
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
and in MAMP I have set line 234 in php.5.4.10.ini to memory_limit = 256M

Comment: @Paul: As I said in my answer, Drush is telling you in the error message that your memory limit is set to 32M. Drush is also telling you exactly which php.ini you need to edit to fix the problem.  If php.5.4.10.ini is the same file as /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini, then I'm not sure what to tell you, but try looking in that file first, and see if there are any other lines that set memory_limit (e.g. `grep memory_limit /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini`)

Comment: Thank you Greg for your persistence with me. You were right. I am still confused why changing the memory_limit in the MAMP interface does not reflect in Drush, but I manually changed the file (as opposed to using the MAMP Pro interface) and it works.

Comment: I'm not on MAMP, but my expectation is that the MAMP interface probably edits just the php.ini for the web server.  It is useful to have a separate php.ini for Drush, in case you want to secure your webserver to a greater degree than Drush allows (e.g. if you want to prevent exec from the webserver, etc.)