# Permissions checkboxes have disappeared on the Admin page for administrator users

Tags: users

All of the checkboxes on the Permissions page (`/admin/people/permissions`) have disappeared.

**I see the permissions for a split second as the page loads before they disappear, so I think this is a Javascript or CSS issue.**

Also, if I edit a single role's permissions (i.e., `/admin/people/permissions/3`), the checkboxes are there. This only happens when using the main permissions page.

**Example of the disappearing checkboxes:**

[image: permissions page with no checkboxes]

**What I've done**

- I've switched my theme and admin theme to Stark to make sure my theme wasn't hiding the permissions.
- I was using the jQuery Multi module to upgrade jQueryUI for some custom scripts, so I disabled that.
- I've searched if anyone else has had this issue, and the only thing I've found is https://drupal.org/node/1649186. I'm not familiar with Organic Groups, and I haven't renamed any machine names, so that post didn't get me very far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh my, I just discovered what it is and I feel really ridiculous... I'm using the admin menu module, and in the configuration, under "System tweaks", there is an option "Collapse module groups on the Permissions page". It is checked. The checkboxes weren't hidden after all. The groups were just collapsed... Maybe I just need a break and another cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by dissappear?

it could be a memory issue

from this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death)

[image]

or are you using the overlay? have you tried disabling it? (the overlay).

Comment: By disappear, I mean as the page is loading, I see all the checkboxes for a split moment, then when the page is fully loaded, they all disappear. I'm not using the overlay. It is disabled.

Setting the memory_limit didn't help. I did, however, recently switch AMP stacks on my Mac OSX from MAMP to Aquia Dev Desktop's DAMP, so I suppose there could be another php.ini configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the cause of this, but the obvious solution to get the checkboxes to appear is to disable Javascript in the browser.

This works, but depending on the browser, can make using the rest of the site a pain (if Javascript is turned off everywhere and you have multiple tabs open).