# How to add functions inside block PHP code

Tags: blocks

I have a node block which contains PHP code snippet. I found that if I define a `function` in that block and call it within the block, the code seems to break. I know that I can add the function into a module file or something - but just out of curiosity, is it not possible to define and use functions in a PHP snippet code block? My code is just:

```
<?php

function hello()
{
  echo "hello";
}
hello();
?>
```

When I run this, all I get is a WSOD. But if I directly `echo "hello";` it prints without any problems...

Comment: The code works. I think there might be another reason for WSOD. check your logs.

Comment: [Follow this post for WSOD](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death)

Comment: I have exactly this problem with Drupal 7.59. Funny that the problematic node was imported from D6 and the source of the node already has a function() that I defined earlier, and **it works**! But when I try to edit the page and then preview, it displays WSOD. Also, when I create a new node with "PHP code" format, it works well with simple PHP calls like ``print()`` or ``date()``, but when I create any own function (even empty!) - it displays WSOD as you described. Did you find the solution?