# WSOD - White screen of death only for administrator

Tags: wsod

I'm Getting white screen of death only for administrator user for the Drupal site i'm working on. I don't have any problem with users of other roles.

Once I try to log in using admin credentials I'm getting white screen of death (In Chrome - "This site can't be reached"). Then I have to type www.mysite.com/user/logout to logout admin session.

I have removed last two modules I installed to make sure that those modules does not interfere. Please help me regarding this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks i have enabled error report as in the thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted and the error  showed that lately uninstalled module broke something and so i copied the module to the module folder and used drush to clear the cache. And did the uninstallation again. Thanks for the help